# Apple Developer Program: invite 3rd party company as Admin or Member?

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program, apple-id

The company I work for owns an iOS Apple Developer account and I'm responsible for managing this account (I'm the Agent). We have hired a 3rd party company to build and release an iPhone app for us.

We would like to give them access to our developer account to publish the app, but was wondering what level of access the would require.

Obviously, I don't want to give them login credentials to our appleID, and I don't want them to have any visibility to financial and legal info on our developer account. 
I took a look at the information [here](https://developer.apple.com/programs/roles/) but still can't decide if they should be "Admin" or "User".

Any thoughts based on your experience? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to review the roles in iTunes Connect, not the Developer Center, for publishing capabilities: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW24

If the deep link doesn't work, (and even if it does, you'll want to review the whole doc): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/About.html and drill down through the "Setting up user accounts" section.